# wcvendor hide product orders by product category and limit the sale price

Tags: function, woocommerce, vendor

is there someone there who can help me?

1. I use wcvendor, I want to hide product orders by product category, on the seller's dashboard,
   (say product category A)
   so if a customer buys a product categorized as A, it will not be displayed on the seller's order dashboard,
2. I use this code to limit regular prices

> ```
> /* WC Vendors Pro -- Require a minimum, and a maximum price for vendors when adding/editing a product */
> add_filter( 'wcv_product_price', 'price_min_max' ); 
> function price_min_max( $args ){ 
>       $args[ 'custom_attributes' ] = array( 
>           'data-rules' => 'decimal|range[10,100]', 
>           'data-error' => __( 'Price should be a number and between $10 and $100', 'wcvendors-pro' )
>       ); 
>       return $args; 
> }
> ```

but how to limit the sale price, when the seller makes the sale price, when the seller uploads the product or edits the product
(say the lowest price of $ 2) so the seller cannot make the sale price under $ 2
thank you

Comment: I see that you are new, avoid asking low-effort question. Include your code on the questions and show what you have tried so far. Consider reading this guide from about asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @L7c1f3r I have updated my question,
hope you can help me